# Record and send wifi signal from raspberry pi to mySQL server in my laptop

Tags: mysql, wifi

I'm trying to record and send the WiFi signal that I get from this command and send it to MySQL: `watch -n 1 cat /proc/net/wireless` (which gives me three values: signal strength, link, and noise). I've been experimenting with this code:

```
for II in $(seq 1 111); 
do 
wifisig="grep wlan0  /proc/net/wireless | awk '{ print $3,$4,$5 }'" 

echo $wifisig

sleep 1
done
```

I've already established a remote connection to MySQL but I also need the code to send the string results to MySQL. Any help, please.

Comment: Answer updated. Is this what you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I got you. Try this:

```
var3=$(grep wlan0 /proc/net/wireless | awk '{print $3 }')
var4=$(grep wlan0 /proc/net/wireless | awk '{print $4 }')
var5=$(grep wlan0 /proc/net/wireless | awk '{print $5 }')
mysql database_name -u user_name -p -e "insert into table_name values($var3, $var4, $var5)"
```

Or, echo your result into a CSV file.

Create a database, create a table, and load data into database by

```
$ mysql database_name -e "LOAD DATA INFILE './csvfile' INTO TABLE table_name FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','"
```

Here's the [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html)